# Java seems to be truncating long string result from MS-SQL query

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, xml

So I've got a query in a JSP class that retrieves, basically, the entire contents of a table as a string using MS SQL's "FOR XML AUTO" feature.

I.e., `select * from userdata for xml auto`.

The problem is that the result is being truncated at around 2033 characters.  There's no unusual character at that point or anything; the break occurs right in the middle of a plain-text attribute.

Is there some obvious thing that's likely causing this, like a limit parameter I need to increase somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: please post some examples of the code you are using.

Comment: Here's the answer: http://aspnetresources.com/blog/executescalar_truncates_xml.aspx

Answer (score 2):

How are you reading in the result?

If you're using ResultSet.getString() I would first try replacing that with ResultSet.getBinaryInput() or getCharacterStream(), then make sure you read in the contents fully before closing the stream.

That's a much better way to do it, in case you end up with a giant data set you won't need to keep the whole thing in memory (especially if you use SAX to pick out the information you need, rather then building a DOM tree)